# How to access specific element of array stored in arraylist?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have following code

```
List<double[]> alParent = new ArrayList<>();
alParent.add(new double[]{15.22,25.22});
alParent.add(new double[]{1.1,2.3});
double tempone[] = {1,2};
double temptwo[] = {4,5};
alParent.add(tempone);
alParent.add(temptwo);
```

I have stored array of type `double[]` inside arraylist. 
I want to access elements from arraylist which are on first position and second position `double[]` array. For my example I want to access `15.22,1.1,1,4` and `25.22,2.3,2,5` separately. Is there any way i can get specific elements stored inside arraylist?
Also, if i have more elements in arraylist how do i get my desire result?

Comment: Firstly, I would start using generics: `List<double[]> alParent = new ArrayList<>();`. Next, have a look at the `ArrayList` documentation - see which of those methods sounds like it will *get* a specific element...

Comment: `List.get(index)` returns item at a specific index and then select desired double value from array. for example `alParent.get(0)[0]` will return fist arrays 0th element i.e. 15.22

Comment: @JonSkeet I am not looking for direct method. Is there any other way i can do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "I am not looking for direct method"? It's not clear what you're expecting here, but `alParent.get(row)[column]` is about as simple as it gets... if you want all the elements in a given column, just iterate over the rows...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use blow code:

```
double temp1[] = new double[alParent.size()];    
double temp2[] = new double[alParent.size()];    
for (int i = 0; i < alParent.size(); i++) {    
    temp1[i] = alParent.get(i)[0];    
    temp2[i] = alParent.get(i)[1];    
}
```

temp1 and temp2 are arrays you want.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have an array, `arr = [2, 4, 5, 6]`, and we want to store all elements into an empty `ArrayList`.

```java
int arr[] = {2,4,5,6}; 
ArrayList<Integer> al =  new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    int num = arr[i];
    al.add(i, num);
}

// print the value of ArrayList 
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    System.out.println(al.get(i));
}
```